# Refreshing page with Query String

Tags: php, html

How can I refresh a page automatically after a given time period with a variable attached to it?

This is what I have tried but no luck.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" <?php echo 'url="game.php?id=' .  $id . '"'?>>
```

At the moment it ignores the the php code completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just a little problem

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;<?php echo 'url=game.php?id=' .  $id; ?>" />
```

Comment: what does the ; after <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; do exactly?

Comment: @JohnAyers It's like giving a variable to a predefined function refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; <?php echo 'URL=game.php?id=' .  $id ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=<?php..?>">
```

content attribute have both time in sec and url separated by semi-colon